# Auto-Renew option not displaying membership contribution page

Tags: civimember

Anyone know why the checkbox that allows memberships to automatically renew would not appear? Everything in the membership type and the contribution page settings is correct, providing the option to renew. We have one site that this is happening on and can't quite figure out what it could be. First time I'm seeing this, so wanted to see if anyone else had experience this before.

When a membership is selected it the space where the check box should appear expands, but is empty. When inspecting source it shows as follows:

```
<div class="crm-section auto-renew">
     <div class="label"></div>
     <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

But should be something like this

```
<div id="allow_auto_renew" style="display: block;">
        <div class="crm-section auto-renew">
            <div class="label"></div>
            <div class="content">
                 <input id="auto_renew" name="auto_renew" type="checkbox" value="1" class="form-checkbox" readonly="readonly" checked="checked">&nbsp;<label for="auto_renew">Please renew my membership automatically.</label>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

This is running on CiviCRM 4.6.9 and WordPress 4.3.1.

Not using a price set,just the membership tab on the contrition page options.

Comment: What version of Civi?

Comment: Sorry, meant to add more to that comment:

1. What version of Civi?
2. Are you using a price set on the contribution pages?

We were seeing some behavior similar to this when using a price set with a select field. A patch was submitted that fixed this behavior, mostly: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17197

Answer (score 1):

I've found that this happens if Pay Later is selected in the contribution - and this is not the behaviour I'd expect. If I turn off Pay Later, the auto-renew checkbox is ticked - but also readonly, which is also not what I've expect for an optional auto-renew. I'm on 4.6.14 and Drupal. Anyway: this might get you going.

[Here's my similar question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10048/auto-renew-option-not-appearing-for-membership)