# Auto-renew option not appearing for membership

Tags: civimember, auto-renew

In Civi 4.6.12 I am testing recurring PayPal Pro payments for a membership.

A simple recurring contribution works OK once [CRM-16698](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16698) in place.

However when testing with a new membership, no option for auto-renew appears. [CRM-17197](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17197) fixed a similar issue when a price-set is used. Any suggestions for fixing this without a price-set?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: I've found that enabling Pay Later on the contribution page is what is stopping the "Please renew my membership automatically" checkbox to appear. Does that sounds right?  With an optional auto-renew, I'd simply expect opting for pay later to disable this checkbox.  In 4.6.14 this is around line 927 in CRM/Member/BAO/Membership.php

With Pay Later disabled, the checkbox is readonly (even though Auto-renew is optional for the membership) - not tracked down why this is yet.

Answer (score 2):

Chris,

I just tested this on my site, and you're right.

If you have the "Pay Later" option selected, the auto-renewal checkbox does not appear.

The checkbox should always appear, and then when the page goes through verification if 'Pay Later' is selected, and the 'auto-renew' box is selected, that should throw an error to the user.

I've created an issue report on this:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18299

Comment: Thanks. There's also the problem of the checkbox being readonly and checked when auto-renew is optional which I'm seeing on 4.6.14, which also needs sorting. I haven't had a chance to look at this any more yet.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment: I must have accidentally chosen Required at some point in my testing.

Comment: In JavaScript I can untick and hide the auto-renew box (and show it again). However I don't know where the verification happens server side.

Here's an addition toggleConfirmButton() in crm/contribute/form/contribution/Main.tpl ie before the line if (flag === true) {


`if( processorTypeId==0){

        cj("#auto_renew").prop('checked', false );

        cj("#allow_auto_renew").hide();
      } else {
        cj("#allow_auto_renew").show();
      }`

Comment: I added the patches as shown in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18299 and the auto-renew option now displays properly.   The system will throw an error if auto-renew and pay later are both selected by the user.

Comment: Just a note that this behavior has always existed:  See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14924.

Comment: Weird, as they evidently fixed in in 4.5 or 4.6 because it worked.   Guess they haven't gone through their open issues now they 4.6 and 4.7 are out.