# Auto-Renew Membership option not displayed v4.7.2

Tags: civimember, joomla, 4.7, auto-renew

CiviCRM 4.7.2, Joomla 3.4.8, MySql 5.5.45, PHP 5.5.30

I'm seeing a similar issue as seen in this thread: [Auto-renew option not appearing for membership](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10048/auto-renew-option-not-appearing-for-membership)

The auto-renew function was working fine, as far as I can tell, up to v4.6.8, but after the upgrade to 4.7.1/4.7.2/4.7.3/4.7.4 it is not appearing on either the initial membership page, nor the membership renewal page.   All appropriate auto-renew options on the membership type, and elsewhere are correctly set.

**UPDATE** 2016-03-26 - turns out that if you have your membership prices set to auto-renew, and the Pay Later option configured, the Auto Renew options does NOT appear on the membership signup/renewal page.

This is NOT using a price set for the membership prices.

I've created an issue on this:
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18299